# Disambiguating overloaded member functions with non-type template parameters in mutiple inheritance class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have the following small program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Field1 {
    using Self_t = Field1;

public:
    template<unsigned int KEY, std::enable_if_t<KEY == 1, Self_t>*>
    int get() {
        return 1;
    }
};

class Field2 {
    using Self_t = Field2;

public:
    template<unsigned int KEY, std::enable_if_t<KEY == 2, Self_t>*>
    char get() {
        return 'a';
    }
};

template<typename FIRST, typename ... REST>
class _Container<FIRST, REST...> : public FIRST, public REST ... {
    using FIRST::get;
    using REST::get ...;
};

template<typename ... FIELDS>
class Container: public _Container<FIELDS...> {};

int main(int, char*[]) {
    Container<Field1, Field2> fred;
    std::cout << fred.get<1>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output from gcc 10.2.0 is

```
   ./src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../src/main.cpp:34:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Container<Field1, Field2>::get<1>()’
   34 |  std::cout << fred.get<1>() << std::endl;
      |                           ^
../src/main.cpp:8:6: note: candidate: ‘template<unsigned int KEY, std::enable_if_t<(KEY == 1), Field1>* <anonymous> > int Field1::get()’
    8 |  int get() {
      |      ^~~
../src/main.cpp:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../src/main.cpp:34:27: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
   34 |  std::cout << fred.get<1>() << std::endl;
      |                           ^
../src/main.cpp:17:7: note: candidate: ‘template<unsigned int KEY, std::enable_if_t<(KEY == 2), Field2>* <anonymous> > char Field2::get()’
   17 |  char get() {
      |       ^~~
../src/main.cpp:17:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/exception:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from ../src/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits: In substitution of ‘template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = Field2]’:
../src/main.cpp:16:69:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:2554:11: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, Field2>’
 2554 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Clang produces a rather more condensed set of error messages:

```
../src/main.cpp:36:20: error: no matching member function for call to 'get'
        std::cout << fred.get<1>() << std::endl;
                     ~~~~~^~~~~~
../src/main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
        int get() {
            ^
../src/main.cpp:19:7: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
        char get() {
             ^
```

As far I can make out, the template parameter lists of each of the `get` functions are different and that when trying to resolve a `get` for `fred`, all the `get` functions in the base clases are considered equal candidates. My intention is that all but one of `get` functions should fail SFINAE. This doesn't seem to be happening.

I've obviously misunderstood something important here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
template<unsigned int KEY, std::enable_if_t<KEY == 1, Self_t>*>
int get() {
  return 1;
}
    
// ...

f.get<1>();
```

This function takes two template parameters, but you have only provided one. Either pass the second one as well when calling the function, or provide a default argument for the second template parameter so that only one is required. I also don't see the need for `Self_t` here.

```cpp
template <unsigned int KEY, std::enable_if_t<KEY == 1>* = nullptr>
int get() {
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd been banging my head on this all weekend.